# Check whether an ideal is maximal or prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> **Problem.** Check whether the following ideals are maximal or prime in $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,X_2]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[X_1,X_2]$:
>   i) $(X_1,X_2)$
>   ii) $(X_1+X_2)$
>   iii) $(X_1,X_2,2)$
>   iv) $(X_1+X_2^2,X_1^2+X_2)$

I know the definitions of these and I know how these ideals look like. I also know that "modding out" a prime ideal yields an integral domain, and a maximal ideal yields a field. I also know that maximal implies prime. Is there a general approach to this problem?

Comment: Modding out by a prime ideal yields an integral domain (not a field), and modding out by a maximal ideal yields a field.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I confused things in my head.

Comment: Not exactly my meat, but it seems to me that you have to use the method of ingenious devices, mostly. In some cases, you can easily find what the quotient looks like (note: not “how” it looks like). In the last case, I’d draw the associated picture, noticing that $y=-x^2$ and $x=-y^2$ intersect in two separate points, so you can find functions that vanish at one and not the other.

Comment: I don't see how this helps me here :(

Comment: why don't you just try with whatever you know? what do you think will $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,X_2]/(X_1,X_2)$ be?

Comment: Oh, I know that $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/(X,Y)=\mathbb{Z}$ thus, $(X,Y)$ is prime, the difficult part of this problem are the other 3. I can't "picture" what polynomials would be left if we mod out say $(X+Y²,X²+Y)$.

Comment: Ok.. what do you think $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,X_2]/(X_1+X_2)$ might be??

Comment: This is exactly the part where I get confused. I know that $(X+Y)=\{f*(X+Y)|f\in\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]\}$. So if we mod that out we are left with the polynomials which don't have a factor of $(X+Y)$?

Comment: Do you mean $(X+Y)$ when you write $(X,Y)$

Comment: Oops, yes I did

Comment: Ok... by going mod $(X_1,X_2)$ you mean that $(X_1,X_2)=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,x_2]$... i.e., we see $X_1=0$ and $X_2=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,x_2]$..SO, we would end up with just $\mathbb{Z}$... Now, by going mod $[X_1+X_2]$ what does it mean?

Comment: We would have $(X+Y)=0$ in $Z[X,Y]$ which means all polynomials that have a factor of $(X+Y)$ would be modded out, right?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik For part (iv) (in $\Bbb{Q}[X_1, X_2]$), we see that the ideal $I = (X_1^2 + X_2, X_1 + X_2^2)$ is not prime because $[X_2(X_1+X_2^2)+X_1(X_1^2+X_2)] - [X_2^2(X_1^2+X_2) + X_1^2(X_1+X_2^2)] = 2X_1X_2-2X_1^2X_2^2 = 2X_1X_2(1-X_1X_2) \in I$ but neither $2X_1X_2$ nor $1-X_1X_2$ are in $I$. It is also not maximal since $X_1X_2$ does not have an inverse, right?